# Unable to tap on Apple ID in app store iphone 5s

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, apple-id, ios

I am using iPhone 5s. I checked on various site on how to sign out of apple id in app store, but I am unable to select the apple Id since it is coming in grey color (normally it is shown in blue). I also have my restriction off in general settings. Because of this error, I am also not able to download anything from app store in my iPhone. My apple Id account is already verified and I have checked it twice on net.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It may be useful to describe step by step what you're trying to do to logout of the App Store, or the link to the instructions you followed.

Answer (score -1):

Trying to `reset all settings` works.

I don't know why it worked.

Comment: Which settings did you reset?

Comment: I clicked on reset all settings.

Comment: Which settings (in which part of the Settings app) did you reset?

Comment: @patrix Settings->General->Reset->Reset All Settings.